# how add an element to the list

Tags: c#, asp.net

i want to add this line to my list but when i put this message error  `results.Add("TOUT");`
how can i add TOUT to the list

this is the method in when i want to add a new element

```
 dynamic results = (from ta in db.client
                               select new
                               {
                                   Name= ta.Name
                               }).Distinct().ToList();
```

Can someone help me to fix this and thank you for your help

Comment: not sure what are you trying to achieve. You're creating a list of objects with property "Name" and later you're trying to add a string to that list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot add a `string` to the list because you are not creating a list of strings. You are creating a list of instances of an anonymous type.
There is almost never a need to create an anonymous type with only one property, so just select the string:

```
(from ta in db.client select ta.Name).Distinct().ToList()
```

or just

```
db.client.Select(ta => ta.Name).Distinct().ToList()
```

This will create a `List<string>`. (Assuming ta.Name is a `string`)

Answer (score 1):

Linq is not created to support data-manipulation but data-query. Thus you have to turn your results in any kind of list where you CAN add elements. e.g:

```
var results = (from ta in db.client
        select new
        {
            Name= ta.Name
        }).Distinct().ToList();
```

Now you can simply add your element by creating an anonymous instance sharing the properties you need.

```
results.Add(new { Name = "TOUT" });
```

Notice that the keyword `dynamic` is not needed here as the returned list is already strongly-typed (although there is no class-definition within your assembly for it, the definition resides within a temporary assembly where the type is called `anonymous`).

EDIT: To simplify things you can also ommit the anonymous type completely and select only the `name`.

So instead of

```
select new { ... }
```

you write

```
select ta.Name
```

Thus you get a list of strings where you can simply add your last element `TOUT`.